# Hide/Show tableView Section when data is removed from the section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my goal is when i swipe a cell and click complete i want a new section to appear f***or example:*** section **1** will populate the cell removed from section **0** and display that way.
i have tried but i couldn't find any successful way to do it.

**in my cellForRowAt**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
       
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        cell.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: list[indexPath.row].color)
        
        return cell
    } else {
        /// show the archived  section 0 cell here
        
        
    }
}
```

**numberOfSection**

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2



    // this method handles row completion
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let complete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete") { (action, sourceView, completionHander) in
        self.list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        /// delete the table view row
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        completionHander(true)
    }
    complete.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    complete.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
    let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [complete])
    return swipeConfiguration
    
}
```

***any help would be appreciated.***

Comment: There is no indication in your code that you have different table sections.

Comment: check now please if more clarification is needed. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In TableView you can add or remove number of section in delegate

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
if <condition for showing 2 section in tableview>{
    return 2
}else {
    return 1
}
}
```

after observed your code I think you want show number of section is equal to number of list count for this

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.list.count

}
```

Comment: thank you ron gaholt, what i want is when cell is removed from section 0, it will come to section 1.

Comment: Are you reload table after remove cell